# How to generate state and action table in YACC/Bison?

Tags: c, parsing, yacc, lex

I am clueless about how I can print a LALR(1) parsing table from the yacc program. I know that behind the scene, yacc converts the grammar into parsing table, with other extra C code.

I would like to print the states, as well as the actions (shift, reduce and accept) on the console, similar to this [image](https://static.javatpoint.com/compiler/images/shift-reduce-parsing1.png). I've come up with [this](https://github.com/Ashvith/YACCCustomLanguage). The program prints `Valid`, if it follows the grammar rule, else `Invalid declaration`.

Comment: Are you trying to answer a homework question, or are you looking to build a tool which can produce a compact parser trace for arbitrary grammars?

Comment: @rici Not a homework question, but a mini-project that I have to submit. No worries, I can manage it with trace, and remove the additional text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "parsing table".

As you say in your first paragraph, a parsing table drives the parser; it lists the possible transitions from each parser state. Bison will print the entire state table in a file with prefix `.output` if you use the commandline option `--report=states,itemsets`. You can get it as a Graphviz file as well, although that's only useful for small grammars, using the `--graph` option.

However, the image you link in the second paragraph does not show a parsing table. What it shows is the progress of the parser with a specific input. This is usually called a "trace" and bison can produce that as well. You need to do two things:

1. Provide the `-t` command-line option (which you can also write out as `--debug`), which causes tracing code to be generated.
2. Set the global variable `yydebug` to `1` in your `main()` function. Please note that `yydebug` won't exist unless you followed step 1.

Comment: I believe that the flag I was looking for, was probably `--report=states,itemsets`, as it is generating states, and the shift and reduce actions that I wanted. I'll make some modifications, should have been more clearer in the post.

Comment: @AshvithShetty: Ok. There are other options for the report as well. Type `bison --help` to get a full list.

Comment: Would it be possible to send the trace into the file, and convert it into a table? Any such parameters for the same?

Comment: Traces are sent to `stderr`; you can redirect that to a file easily enough. But I don't know of any tools which can parse and reformat the output. The generated code uses macros, but it's not really designed for refactoring. You might be able to edit it or redefine macros to make it  easier to parse.